# java how to get superclass reference in subclass

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I have 3 classes:

`class Superclass`...

```
public class Generic{
     public Generic(Superclass s){...}
}
```

And a subclass extending Superclass

```
class SubClass extends Superclass{
      public void methodM(){
           Generic g = new Generic(???);
           ...
      }
}
```

In `methodM` I use the constructor `Generic` and I want to pass a reference to the Superclass instance extended by Subclass. So I don't want to do something like `new Generic(new Superclass)`, rather something like: `new Generic(super.IdontKnowWhat)`

thank you

Comment: You should point us to a concrete use case, because we can smell bad design otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to the current object is implicitly a reference to a superclass as well (as it extends it).

So you should be able to do

```
 Generic g = new Generic(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call it as `super.parameter` as super is an inbuilt keyword used to reference the super class fields. You can read about `super` in [the java docs tutorial for super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Answer (score 0):

U can pass the reference of the subclass as it extends the superclass..
But it depends on what methods u want to acssess..If u pass reference of subclass then u should acssess the methods of subclass through the object received in constructor of Generic class..
So u should construct the new object of superclass in case u want to acssess methods of superclass..